# GDB shows different value between register and stack value

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64

I tried GDB, and it shows different value between register and stack value.
It has to print "1 2 3 4 5 6", but it shows "P\231UUUU".
It didn't overwritten and I made correct break point.

Did I miss something, or is it the correct representation? I tried to find out the reason, but I couldn't find it...

I do not have code for this, I only have an executable file.

```
0x00005555555558fd <+0>: push %rbp 
0x00005555555558fe <+1>: mov %rsp,%rbp 
0x0000555555555901 <+4>: sub $0x70,%rsp 
0x0000555555555905 <+8>: mov %rdi,-0x68(%rbp) 
=> 0x0000555555555909 <+12>: lea 0x3970(%rip),%rax
```

From here I made break at 0x0000555555555909.

```
 (gdb) x/s $rdi 0x555555559950
  input_strings+400: "1 2 3 4 5 6"
```

but when I do `(gdb) x/s $rbp -0x68`

```
0x7fffffffe1a8: "P\231UUUU"
```

Comment: This is really hard to understand. Please post your code and paste a transcript of your GDB session.

Comment: @SupportUkraine oh I just realized that my bad...

Comment: And maybe also mention the processor type and your platform

Comment: @SupportUkraine thank you so much. is it more readable?

Comment: Yes, it's better now.... but I wouldn't start the lines with the `>` character. Just start with 4 spaces. That's how code is normally formatted on SO

Comment: `x/s $rbp -0x68` dumps the pointer value itself as a string.  `mov %rdi,-0x68(%rbp)` stored a pointer, it didn't copy the string.  You'd need another level of indirection in GDB, like dump a qword, copy/paste it, dump that.  Or `x/s *(char*)($rbp-0x68)` maybe; note the `*` deref operator in front of the cast.